# How to implement decodeObjectOfClasses in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble finding the correct way to conform the the `NSSecureCoding` protocol in **Swift**, specifically when decoding objects that is an array of other objects.

I can't create an `NSSet` of class types in swift.

In Objective-C I would use

```
self.books = [aDecoder decodeObjectOfClasses:[NSSet setWithObjects:[NSArray class], [Book class], nil] forKey:@"books"];
```

in Swift I'm having issues creating the `NSSet` like this :

```
self.books = aDecoder.decodeObjectOfClasses(NSSet().setByAddingObject(NSArray.self).setByAddingObject(Book.self), forKey:"books")
```

Here's the error:

```
Type 'NSArray.Type' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

Comment: NSSet(objects: [NSArray.self, Book.self])

Comment: Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments.

try it out in a playground

class Book {
    
}

class Test {
    var set = NSSet(objects: [NSArray.self, Book.self])
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a class array in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174510/how-to-create-a-class-array-in-swift)

Comment: @TimSawtell: it should work in the latest versions

Comment: @user102008 yep it now compiles fine but I get a run time exception: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'value for key 'strings' was of unexpected class 'NSArray'. Allowed classes are '{(
        (
        NSArray,
        NSString
    )
)}

Radar filed with Apple (id: 17617664) . It's still open.

Answer (score 5):

For simple objects:

```
self.myObject = aDecoder.decodeObjectOfClass(MyObject.self, forKey: "myObject")!
```

Since Swift 3.0:

```
self.myObject = aDecoder.decodeObject(of:MyObject.self, forKey: "myObject")!
```

Swift 4

```
aDecoder.decodeObject(of: [NSArray.self, Book.self], forKey: "books") as? [Book]
```

For nested objects:

```
NSSet(objects: [NSArray.self, Book.self])
```

Comment: For Swift 4: `aDecoder.decodeObject(of: [NSArray.self, Book.self], forKey: "books") as? [Book]`

Comment: Also since iOS 14 there is new api: `decodeArrayOfObjects(ofClass: Book.self, forKey: "books")`

Answer (score 1):

**[Declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCoder/decodeObjectOfClasses:forKey:)**

*SWIFT*

```
func decodeObjectOfClasses(_ classes: NSSet,
                    forKey key: String) -> AnyObject?
```

Since Swift 3.0:

```
func decodeObject<DecodedObjectType where DecodedObjectType : NSCoding, DecodedObjectType : NSObject>(of cls: DecodedObjectType.Type, forKey key: String) -> DecodedObjectType?
```

*OBJECTIVE-C*

```
- (id)decodeObjectOfClasses:(NSSet *)classes
                     forKey:(NSString *)key

let books: AnyObject? = aDecoder.decodeObjectOfClasses(NSSet().setByAddingObject(NSArray.self).setByAddingObject(Book.self), forKey:"books")
```

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly the same as when I originally posted the question, but I've achieved what I wanted by using typed collections as seen below

```
class Bookshelf: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
    var authors = [Author]()
    var books = [Book]()

    override init () {
        super.init()
    }

    @objc func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.authors, forKey: "authors")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.books, forKey: "books")
    }

    @objc required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.authors = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("authors") as? [Author])!
        self.books = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("books") as? [Book])!
    }

    @objc static func supportsSecureCoding() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: This `init(coder:)` function is not actually using secure coding. In order to decode securely it needs to know the class ahead of time—so you need to use `decodeObject(of:forKey:)`. More details on this here: http://nshipster.com/nssecurecoding/