# How to create a class array in Swift

Tags: class, swift

In objective c, I could create a class array and use it in a method

```
NSArray *classes = @[[NSAttributedString class]];
NSArray *items = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:classes
                                           options:nil];
```

However, swift has no "class" function. Returning a Metatype for a class results in an error

```
    let aClass : AnyClass!  = NSAttributedString.self
    //or let aClass:AnyClass! = NSAttributedString.classForArchiver()

    let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()

    let classes = [aClass]

    let objects = pasteboard.readObjectsForClasses(classes, options: nil)
```

the final line results in "fatal error: array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C"

How can I create a class array in Swift?

Comment: another way is `objc_getClass("NSAttributedString")`, but depending on the name of the class as a string is not as good as Sulthan's solution

Comment: Update: it appears that in Xcode 6 beta 3, this code works with no problem

Comment: Update: the problem appears again in Xcode 6 beta 6

Comment: Update: it seems to be fixed again in Xcode 6.1 beta

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Apparently, this has been fixed in Beta 3 so there is no need for workarounds anymore**

I have found a pure Swift hack:

```
func classFromType<T: NSObject>(type: T.Type) -> AnyObject! {
    return T.valueForKey("self") //ask for class indirectly...
}

var clazz: AnyObject = classFromType(NSAttributedString.self)
var classes = [clazz]
```

**Previous answer**

I wasn't able to get the `Class` instance by any means in Swift. It seems it cannot be converted directly from `AnyClass`. For example, the following is not possible (will crash at runtime)

```
var classes: NSMutableArray = []
classes.addObject(NSClassFromString(NSAttributedString.className()))
```

So I went into Obj-C and defined a simple `NSMutableArray` category:

```
@implementation NSMutableArray (ClassArray)

- (void)addClassByName:(NSString *)className {
    [self addObject:NSClassFromString(className)];
}

@end
```

Then

```
var classes: NSMutableArray = []
classes.addClassByName(NSAttributedString.className())
```

works but it is a bit of a hack.

Comment: it appears that in Xcode 6 beta 3, this hack is not necessary anymore

Comment: I have this in my code: `class MyTeam: NSMutableArray {...}` and I want to use swift declaration. How do I do it?

Comment: it is not a pure swift cause it requires `NSObject` as a superclass

Comment: @fnc12 Well, this uses to be a hack anyway. You don't need that any more because the bug has been fixed.

Comment: @Sulthan it there any way to answer the question without objc?

Comment: @fnc12 In current Swift the OP's code will work without any workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

in **Swift 2.0** you can use

```
let urls = _pasteboard.readObjectsForClasses([NSURL.self, NSString.self], options: nil)
```

as `<ClassName>.self` returns `AnyClass` value

Answer (score 1):

It rather looks as if the array bridge works on AnyObject, but your aClass is not AnyObject, it's AnyClass! - the stack trace at the error says

```
Swift._arrayBridgeToObjectiveC <A, B>(Swift.Array<A>) -> Swift.Array<B> ()
```

and the assembler prior to it stopping looks as if they are deliberately trapping on it not being AnyObject.

Changing your code to

```
var classAsAnyObject : AnyObject = aClass as AnyObject
//var classes = [aClass]
var classes = [classAsAnyObject]
```

causes an immediate crash in objc_retain, as does

```
var array = NSArray(object:aClass)
```

so I guess it's something to do with ARC and classes.

Handling of Classes as objects themselves in Swift seems obscure, to say the least.

It doesn't answer the real question (how do you create an array of classes), but for the application you used as an example, you could circumvent it by doing something like:

```
    var pasteboard = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
    let allObjects = pasteboard.pasteboardItems
    println("allObjects=\(allObjects)")
    for item : AnyObject in allObjects {
        println("item=\(object_getClassName(item))")
        if let pbi = item as? NSPasteboardItem {
            println("item.types=\(pbi.types)")
            let str = pbi.stringForType("public.utf8-plain-text")
            println("item as string \(str)")
        }
    }
```